# Smooth scroll fix when i have a anchor with .html

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, smoothing

Hi there i have a navigation with scroll intoVIEW , but i want to fix when i click on href like index.html not working , any fixes

```
document
  .querySelector(".navigation__ul")
  .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.classList.contains("navigation__link")) {
      const id = e.target.getAttribute("href");
      document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      navigation.classList.toggle("open");
      overlay.classList.toggle("nav__overlay");
    }

    if (!navigation.classList.contains("open")) {
      hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
    }
  });
```

Comment: I recommend that you set up an fiddle, so we can try this out and fix it for you. Until then, check out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_smooth_scroll_jquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vhseL0wg/1/

Comment: The fiddle is incomplete. You've added tags such as #hero, but no actual elements for it to scroll to.

Comment: just click on element with .html on anchor. the problem is not the # is the .html multi page